# Filling grid without forming rectangles

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

Hi so recently my teacher give me a problem to research: He asked me to find a general case of  Size of maximal set of points in an n X n (side length) grid such that no 4-set of it forms a rectangle with horizontal/vertical sides. He also gave me this link to help me find the fisrt few values on http://oeis.org/A072567. However I looked at it for a long time but still don't have a clue. It this question doable with optimizers or direct counting? Can someone provide inspirations? I really need help on this...

Comment: Have you read the comments to the OEIS sequence?

Comment: Not sure but I dont think they are helpful